# I want to change my Website Page og:url

Tags: facebook-opengraph

On my wordpress website I have: (in view source)

```
meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myoldwebsite"
```

Now I want to change it to

```
meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mynewwebsite.com"/
```

This is generated through plugin and I have found the plugin code which is fetching this `og:url`, below is the code:

```
$fb_url=get_permalink();
    if (is_front_page()) {
        /* Fix homepage type when it's a static page */
        $fb_url=get_option('home').(intval($fb_url_add_trailing)==1 ? '/' : '');
        $fb_type=trim($fb_type_homepage=='' ? 'website' : $fb_type_homepage);
    }
    if (trim($post->post_excerpt)!='') {
        //If there's an excerpt that's what we'll use
        $fb_desc=trim($post->post_excerpt);
```

I am not getting where and what to change so that when I view source my website page, then I can see the changed `og:url`

```
meta property="og:url" content="http://www.myoldwebsite.com"/
```

After code changing, I want this to appear:

```
meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mynewwebsite.com"/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hack it, you can probably replace

```
$fb_url=get_option('home').(intval($fb_url_add_trailing)==1 ? '/' : '');
```

with

```
$fb_url='http://www.mynewwebsite.com';
```

Be advised; this is a hack. You're changing a plug-in. I'm no Wordpress expert but as soon as you update the plugin this code will probably reset. Probably better to find the content of the `home` variable and change that.